# Share an EGLImage Between Different Applications / Processes on Embedded Linux / ARM

Tags: c++, opengl-es-2.0, embedded-linux, egl

I'm currently designing some EGL 1.4/OpenGL ES 2.0 applications in C++ on an Embedded Linux/ARM platform that doesn't have any windowing system.

Basically, I want to share textures/renderbuffers between independent applications -- let's call them app "A" and app "B".

To do so, I first thought of downloading the render buffer using `glReadPixels()` (from app A) in a buffer that is in shared memory then opening this shared memory from app B and upload the the buffer using `glTexImage2D()` or `glTexSubImage2D()` .

After some initial testing, it turned out that this is quite an unefficient/slow method. So I decided to use the platform's EGL/GLES extensions which (as returned by `eglQueryString()` and `glGetString()`) include:

- [EGL_KHR_image_base](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_image_base.txt)
- [EGL_KHR_image](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_image.txt)
- [EGL_KHR_gl_image](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_gl_image.txt)
- [OES_EGL_image](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image.txt)
- [OES_mapbuffer](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_mapbuffer.txt)

My objective is now to create an `EGLImage` in app A (e.g. from a GL texture, using `EGLImageKHR sharedEglImage = eglCreateImageKHR(dpy, ctx, EGL_GL_TEXTURE_2D_KHR, textureId, imageAttributes)` ) then share this very `sharedEglImage` with app B so it can be mapped as the pixel data of one of app B's own GL textures using `glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES()` .

However, like most of EGL/GL abstractions, `EGLImage` is an opaque structure (i.e. just a `void*` ), it wouldn't make sense to map it to shared memory in order to share it across processes. Hence my question:

Is there a way to share an EGLImage across independent processes ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you will need to make use of the [Gralloc](https://code.google.com/p/gles6410/source/browse/trunk/libgralloc/). Gralloc allocated memory is sharable across processes since that is what the Surface Flinger uses.

This does come with a huge health warning that these APIs are private to the platform and may not be portable between devices or versions.

Edit: the link is to an implementation and will probably not be terribly helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the OS is a X-less, 32-bit-ARM, Linux. Not Android.

Comment: Unfortunately then, you will find this kind of detail being very platform dependent. The best bet is to see if you get any documentation on on the EGL implementation. Or better yet, take a look at the source code.

Comment: Since I do not have access to such documentation (and much less the source code). I would like to know if it is possible to create an EGLImage from a raw C array ? e.g. like such:
    `const size_t bufferSize = width * height * bpp / 8;   uint8_t rawBuffer[bufferSize];   EGLImage img = magicImageCreationFunction(rawBuffer, bufferSize);`

Comment: No it is not. In order to access the memory, the memory must be GPU accessible. This means that you must use a special allocator when allocating the memory. CPU allocated memory will not work since the GPU cannot access it. Besides CPU allocated memory is only visible to one process.

Comment: At least, is it even possible to `memcpy()` (or another "efficient" copy function) the pixel data of an EGLImage ? (I don't want to use `glReadPixels()` )

Comment: Unless you have access to the graphics allocator you cannot create an EGLImage so I think the answer is no. Besides glReadPixels will be as fast as a memcpy. The reason why it is slow is because glReadPixels is copying from uncached memory that may not even exist in system RAM (although on an embedded device it probably does).

Comment: I meant: having _already created_ an EGLImage, is there an alternative to `glReadPixels()` for copying this EGLImage's pixel data into, for instance, a C array ? Put differently: how can I get a pointer to the pixel data of an EGLImage ?